# Orthogonality with Bessel functions of rational order

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

*I tried to ask this question on MSE ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213680/bessel-functions-with-rational-order)), but got no comments or answers. So, I hope someone on MO would advise.*

Given a set of functions $f_{mv}(r,\phi)=J_{v}(k_{mv}r)\cos(v \phi)$ in polar coordinates, where $J_{v}$ denotes Bessel's function of the first kind of $v$th order and $k_{mv}$ denotes the $m$th root of $J'_{v}(k_{mv}a)=0$ at boundary $r=a$, how do we prove that these functions are orthogonal iff $v$ is integer?

[Note that they are tested for orthogonality over $v$ and $m$, as they will be later used to express functions by expansions like $\sum\limits_{v}\sum\limits_{m}c_{mv}f_{mv}$].

And then, for a case where we have rational $v$ (ratio of two integers, $v=M/N$), is there a way to construct a new orthogonal set that is of similar form to the one above (or linearly re-adjust/combine the terms in the original one above to make it orthogonal under such condition)?

Comment: @paul It is intended: if and only if (=iff). Apologies.

Comment: @paul Question was updated to fix this.

Comment: @Francois Done.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions $r\mapsto J_\nu(kr)$ are orthogonal because they are eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint Sturm-Liouville problem. This follows from [Lagrange's](https://books.google.com/books?id=ix2iCQ-o9x4C&pg=PA88) (a.k.a. Green's) [identity](https://books.google.com/books?id=ix2iCQ-o9x4C&pg=PA144), or most explicitly from the relation (e.g. [Lebedev (5.14.3, 5.14.9)](https://books.google.com/books?id=po-6Yxz851MC&pg=PA130))
$$
\int_0^a J_\nu(\alpha r)J_\nu(\beta r)\,r\,dr = \frac{a\beta J_\nu(\alpha a)J_\nu'(\beta a)-a\alpha J_\nu(\beta a)J_\nu'(\alpha a)}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}.
$$
For non-integral $\nu$, this still works but the product with $\cos(\nu\phi)$ won't be single-valued in polar coordinates...

Comment: If we could ignore or avoid the angular multi-valuedness for a moment (e.g. by limiting the chosen domains of $\phi$ in practice), would the product itself be orthogonal for different values of $v$ when $v=M/N$?

Comment: @user135626 Rather the opposite: if $\mu, \nu$ have common denominator $N>1$ (e.g. $\mu=0$, $\smash{\nu=\frac12}$), then $\smash{\int_0^b e^{i(\nu-\mu)\phi}d\phi=0}$ generally requires $b$ to be a multiple of $2N\pi$, not just $2\pi$, i.e. you must *expand* the domain to an $N$-fold cover of the circle.